# AsyncHttp post for JSON in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, post

I am trying to authenticate user by posting username and password to server.

```
result = Rho::AsyncHttp.post( 
                           :url => @myURL , 
                           :body => "[userlogin:{"userid":"user","password":"123"}] 
          &accept=json" 
                        )
```

The response I get tells that there is some format error in sending parameters. How can I write the correct format for parameters above?

Answer (score 0):

Using double quotes in `:body` is resulting in your string getting malformed. Try using single quotes instead of double quotes to make one big string:

```
result = Rho::AsyncHttp.post( 
                           :url => @myURL , 
                           :body => "[userlogin:{'userid':'user','password':'123'}] 
          &accept=json" 
                        )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chris. Server is down. Will tell the response when server is up.